# Using javascript to perform some date calculations/comparisons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Date object and I'm trying to add a year to the today's date. I also have to have a way to compare the date that's in the date object (newly made + one year) and today's date. How do I compare today's date with the date in the variable? The point is, I need to have a way to know if today's date is the same or greater to the expiration date, that way I could redirect users to a different location... thanks all!

here's my Date object

```
var expDate = new Date();
```

Comment: Look up the date.js library. That's what it is for.

Answer (score 1):

The basic JavaScript `Date` object has stuff built in to handle all of that natively.

For adding a year to your date simply do this:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var futureDate = new Date(currentDate);
futureDate.setFullYear(futureDate.getFullYear() + 1);
```

That gets the current day as the date, and then creates a new date, based on today's date and sets the yea to the current year plus 1.

As for the comparison, simply use `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, `==`, and `!=`.  JavaScript understands what to do with those operators when Date objects are involved and will compare the two dates appropriately.

On thing that I might suggest doing (since you only care about the actual date, and not the time element of the `Date` object, is add in this line of code after getting today's date:

```
currentDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

That will set the hour, minute, second, and millisecond values to 0, so that only the date is a factor when doing any comparisons.

For everything that you could ever need to know about the JavaScript `Date` object, check out here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

**Edit:** Fixed syntax issue.

Comment: I have a problem with this... the future date is showing up as a number "1405483200000 " and not July 16 2014. how do i fix this?

Comment: Sorry . . . got excited and tried to do too much in one line.  :) I updated the code in the answer with the correct format to get what you asked for.

Comment: is there a way to condense that? I tried doing this but i get numbers again: var futureDate = currentDate.setFullYear(currentDate.getFullYear()+1);

Comment: Trying to condense it is actually what is causing the problem.  Setting the `futureDate` variable to the `currentDate` variable will simply point the two variables to the same `Date` object.  As a result, any changes made to either variable, will alter the same, shared object.  Creating a new `Date` object, using the `currentDate` value as input, sets up a new object for `futureDate`, so that the two dates can be manipulated independently.